# unobtrusive validation RANGE does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am doing an MVC 3 application. I have a model with `[Range(1, 175, ErrorMessage="Invalid")]`.

On one of the controllers the view renders perfectly with all markup for validation. On a second Controller with the same setup the Range validation which is done on a dropdownlist, does not appear on the html markup. I have validation and unostrusiveValidation true on `config.web`. I am using `LINQTOSQL` and I have done a partial class to add the additional metadata. The field does pick up the `[Display(Name="State")]`, but the Range is not.

```
 <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.carta.INVprovincia)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.carta.INVprovincia, Model.provinciaItems, new { @class = "ddlsmall" }) <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.carta.INVprovincia)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(x => x.carta.INVmunicipio)</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.carta.INVmunicipio, Model.municipiosItems, new { @class = "ddlsmall" }) <br /> @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.carta.INVmunicipio)</td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Probably an issue in the second controller?

Comment: Could you show the view in which you have rendered the input element corresponding to this property?

Comment: I added a section of the view. I have Required fields on the view and they do work. It is only the Range which does not.

Comment: well, after a couple of debugs, it just starting working by itself... thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

The Html.XXX helpers won't generate HTML5 `data-*` attributes used by the unobtrusive validation framework if they are not inside a form which seems to be your case. I guess that the form is contained within a parent view. This bug (IMHO) is fixed in ASP.NET MVC 4. A possible workaround is to put the following on the to of your partial view to fake a form and make the helpers believe that they are inside a form:

```
@{
    ViewContext.FormContext = new FormContext();
}
```

Comment: Then this should work fine if those helpers are inside this form. Also make sure you have included both the jquery.validate and jquery.validate-unobtrusivescripts to your page. Also do those dropdownlists contain integer as values? In this case why not using a simple text field for entering integers but you are using dropdowns?

Comment: yes both js are in the header. I am pulling a list of States from the DB with its related ID. and validating against Range(1, 75) if -1 means i have not selected and should give me the validation. but in the markup of the view on the <select data-val-range-min="1" is not being rendered in the page....

Comment: Why are you using the `[Range]` attribute to validate if a selection is made in a dropdown???????????????????? Make the Id property to which the dropdown is bound on your view model a nullable integer and then use the `[Required]` attribute.